# Rails yield and AngularJs router

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, angularjs

I am using angularJs with Rails and I use this layout :

```
!!! 5
%html(lang="en"){"ng-app"=>"MyApp"}
  %head
    %meta(charset="utf-8")
    %meta(http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1")
    %meta(name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0")
    %title= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "MyApp"
    = csrf_meta_tags
    / Le HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML elements
    /[if lt IE 9]
      = javascript_include_tag "http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"

    /[if lt IE 8]
      = stylesheet_link_tag "application-ie", :media => "all"

    = stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all"
    %link(href="assets/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png" rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144")
    %link(href="assets/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png" rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114")
    %link(href="assets/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png" rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72")
    %link(href="assets/apple-touch-icon.png" rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed")
    %link(href="assets/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon")


  %body
    .container.content
      .row-fluid.notifications
        - if alert || notice
          .span12
            - if alert
              .alert.alert-error= alert
            - if notice
              .alert.alert-info= notice


      .row-fluid
        .span12{"ng-view" => ""}
          = yield

    = javascript_include_tag "application"
    = yield :javascript
```

My issue is : When I do to a rails url (Example: Devise sign in url) Angular js remove all content of my yield because no AngularJs route match the current one :

```
window.App = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngResource', 'ng-rails-csrf','ui.bootstrap']).config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider' ,
($routeProvider, $locationProvider) ->
  #$locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
  $locationProvider.html5Mode true
  $routeProvider.when("/applications",
    controller: 'ApplicationListCtrl'
    templateUrl: '/applications.html?l=false'
  )
])
```

How can I manage that?

Answer (score 0):

It may be a little more work than its worth, but my hacky solution to this problem has been rendering essentially empty rails views with nothing but a simple `div` tag with an `ng-view` or `ui-view` directive. So for example, instead of putting the `ng-view` in `application.html.erb`, you would only put it in `show.html.erb` where you want to have Angular templates populate the views instead of rails views.

So your `application.html.erb` might look like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <title>My Application</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
```

And then your `login.html.erb` would be filled with rails logic and a normal erb template. But then when your user logs in, you could redirect them to that essentially empty template I mentioned, that just contains an `ng-view`.

So if they were redirected to `users/show` `show.html.erb` would look like:

```
<section ng-view>

</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

In our app, we use a class level variable in our controller to identify whether a page should include the angular hooks or not.  That way we can toggle them on and off.  In our case, the default behavior is off and we specifically turn it on for the angular areas of our site (because most of our site is not angular).  In the case where most of the site is angular, you could use the variable in reverse.

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def angular_page
    @use_angular = true
  end
  def non_angular_page
    # do nothing
  end
end
```

In layouts/application.html.erb

```
  .row-fluid
    -if @use_angular
      .span12{"ng-view" => ""}
        = yield
    -else
      .span12
        = yield
```